# I want to create a "See all your funds" button on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to JS/JQuery web dev in general.

For a work task I've been asked to come up with a solution where the first 3 funds in a list are shown and if they are invested in more than 3 then there will be a show all your funds button and once clicked it will toggle the rest of the funds.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <title>Check your retirement plan demo</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropdown-component.css" />
            <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body style="background-color:#eaeaea;">

            <div class="container">
                <h2> Dropdown Component</h2>

                <!-- THIS BIT FUNDS START -->
                <section class="main clearfix">

                    <select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                        <option value="-1" selected>Funds in your portfolio (3)</option>
                        <option value="1">fund1 £60,000</option>
                        <option value="2">fund 2 £40,000</option>
                        <option value="3">fund 3 £24,000</option>
                        <option value="4">View all funds &gt;</option>
                        <option value="5">Fund 5 £40,000</option>

                    </select>

                </section>
                <!-- THIS BIT FUNDS END -->

            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {

                    $('#cd-dropdown').dropdown({
                        gutter: 5
                    });

                });

                    </script>

        </body>

        </html>`
```

I'm using jquery dropdown solution to help me with the funds its not got the functionality to hide the funds greater than 3 and toggle them once the see more funds is clicked.

```
 /**
     * jquery.dropdown.js v1.0.0
     * http://www.codrops.com
     *
     * Licensed under the MIT license.
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     *
     * Copyright 2012, Codrops
     * http://www.codrops.com
     */
    ; (function ($, window, undefined) {

        'use strict';

        $.DropDown = function (options, element) {
            this.$el = $(element);
            this._init(options);
        };

        // the options
        $.DropDown.defaults = {
            speed: 300,
            easing: 'ease',
            gutter: 0,
            // initial stack effect
            stack: true,
            // delay between each option animation
            delay: 0,
            // random angle and positions for the options
            random: false,
            // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
            // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
            rotated: false,
            // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
            slidingIn: false,
            onOptionSelect: function (opt) { return false; }
        };

        $.DropDown.prototype = {

            _init: function (options) {

                // options
                this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options);
                this._layout();
                this._initEvents();

            },
            _layout: function () {

                var self = this;
                this.minZIndex = 1000;
                var value = this._transformSelect();
                this.opts = this.listopts.children('li');
                this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
                this.size = { width: this.dd.width(), height: this.dd.height() };

                var elName = this.$el.attr('name'), elId = this.$el.attr('id'),
                    inputName = elName !== undefined ? elName : elId !== undefined ? elId : 'cd-dropdown-' + (new Date()).getTime();

                this.inputEl = $('<input type="hidden" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + value + '"></input>').insertAfter(this.selectlabel);

                this.selectlabel.css('z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount);
                this._positionOpts();
                if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {
                    setTimeout(function () { self.opts.css('transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing); }, 25);
                }

            },
            _transformSelect: function () {

                var optshtml = '', selectlabel = '', value = -1;
                this.$el.children('option').each(function () {

                    var $this = $(this),
                        val = isNaN($this.attr('value')) ? $this.attr('value') : Number($this.attr('value')),
                        classes = $this.attr('class'),
                        selected = $this.attr('selected'),
                        label = $this.text();

                    if (val !== -1) {
                        optshtml +=
                            classes !== undefined ?
                                '<li data-value="' + val + '"id=fundID' + val + '><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
                                '<li data-value="' + val + '"id=fundID' + val + '><span>' + label + '</span></li>';
                    }

                    if (val > 3) {}

                    if (selected) {
                        selectlabel = label;
                        value = val;
                    }

                });

                this.listopts = $('<ul/>').append(optshtml);
                this.selectlabel = $('<span/>').append(selectlabel);
                this.dd = $('<div class="cd-dropdown"/>').append(this.selectlabel, this.listopts).insertAfter(this.$el);
                this.$el.remove();

                return value;

            },
            _positionOpts: function (anim) {

                var self = this;

                this.listopts.css('height', 'auto');
                this.opts
                    .each(function (i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            zIndex: self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
                            top: self.options.slidingIn ? (i + 1) * (self.size.height + self.options.gutter) : 0,
                            left: 0,
                            marginLeft: self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : - self.options.slidingIn : 0,
                            opacity: self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
                            transform: 'none'
                        });
                    });

                if (!this.options.slidingIn) {
                    this.opts
                        .eq(this.optsCount - 1)
                        .css({ top: this.options.stack ? 9 : 0, left: this.options.stack ? 4 : 0, width: this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width, transform: 'none' })
                        .end()
                        .eq(this.optsCount - 2)
                        .css({ top: this.options.stack ? 6 : 0, left: this.options.stack ? 2 : 0, width: this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width, transform: 'none' })
                        .end()
                        .eq(this.optsCount - 3)
                        .css({ top: this.options.stack ? 3 : 0, left: 0, transform: 'none' });
                }

            },
            _initEvents: function () {

                var self = this;

                this.selectlabel.on('mousedown.dropdown', function (event) {
                    self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
                    return false;

                });

                this.opts.on('click.dropdown', function () {
                    if (self.opened) {
                        var opt = $(this);
                        self.options.onOptionSelect(opt);
                        self.inputEl.val(opt.data('value'));
                        self.selectlabel.html(opt.html());
                        self.close();
                    }
                });

            },
            open: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.dd.toggleClass('cd-active');
                this.listopts.css('height', (this.optsCount + 1) * (this.size.height + this.options.gutter));
                this.opts.each(function (i) {

                    $(this).css({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : (i + 1) * (self.size.height + self.options.gutter),
                        left: self.options.random ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - 5) : 0,
                        width: self.size.width,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        transform: self.options.random ?
                            'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 - 5) + 'deg)' :
                            self.options.rotated ?
                                self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
                                    'rotate(-' + (i * 5) + 'deg)' :
                                    'rotate(' + (i * 5) + 'deg)'
                                : 'none',
                        transitionDelay: self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? (i * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : ((self.optsCount - 1 - i) * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : 0
                    });

                });
                this.opened = true;

            },
            close: function () {

                var self = this;
                this.dd.toggleClass('cd-active');
                if (this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions) {
                    this.opts.each(function (i) {
                        $(this).css({ 'transition-delay': self.options.slidingIn ? ((self.optsCount - 1 - i) * self.options.delay) + 'ms' : (i * self.options.delay) + 'ms' });
                    });
                }
                this._positionOpts(true);
                this.opened = false;

            }

        }

        $.fn.dropdown = function (options) {
            var instance = $.data(this, 'dropdown');
            if (typeof options === 'string') {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                this.each(function () {
                    instance[options].apply(instance, args);
                });
            }
            else {
                this.each(function () {
                    instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data(this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown(options, this));
                });
            }
            return instance;
        };

    })(jQuery, window);'
```

Can anybody help me to either come up with a quick solution or point me in the correct direction? Thanks

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, I'd suggest creating a working example of what you've tried so far on a site like https://jsfiddle.net/ or a similar site.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Craig62/wfoktkqg/) I've attached a link. Javascript code isn't the best to look at as I've got minimised modernizer code at the top but you can see the example

Answer (score 1):

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/7d95ymLu/)

You want to create a hidden element on the page that will cache or house the options that you do not want visible.  Then, you would add some CSS to that element and use jQuery to place options into it.

> **HTML**

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Funds in your portfolio (3)</option>
    <option value="1">fund1 £60,000</option>
    <option value="2">fund 2 £40,000</option>
    <option value="3">fund 3 £24,000</option>
    <option value="4">View all funds &gt;</option>
    <option value="5">Fund 5 £40,000</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="View all" class='view_more_button' />
<input type="button" value="View less" class='view_less_button hide' />
```

> **CSS**

```
.hide {
    left: -9999px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -500;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

> **JavaScript**

```
//Create on DOM element dynamically that will house options greater than three.
var blank_input = $('<select>', {
    class: 'hidden_input_field hide',
    name: 'hidden_fields'
});

//This variable caches the master select element.
var master_select_menu = jQuery('#cd-dropdown');

//Put the blank select field in the DOM tree to be select via jQuery selectors.
blank_input.appendTo(jQuery('body'));

jQuery('.view_more_button').on('click', function(e) {
    var place_holder_select_field = jQuery('.hidden_input_field');
    if (place_holder_select_field.children('option').length) {
        jQuery('.moved').each(function(index,element) {
            jQuery(element).appendTo(master_select_menu);
        });
        jQuery(e.target).addClass('hide');
        jQuery('.view_less_button').removeClass('hide');
    }
    master_select_menu.val(-1).change();
});

jQuery('.view_less_button').on('click', function(e) {
    view_three();
    jQuery(e.target).addClass('hide');
    jQuery('.view_more_button').removeClass('hide');
    master_select_menu.val(-1).change();
});

view_three();

//This function gets called as soon as the page loads, where it appends any option element greater than 3 to the hidden select field.
function view_three() {
    jQuery('option').each(function(index, element) {
        var place_holder_select_field = jQuery('.hidden_input_field');
        if (index > 3) {
            jQuery(element).addClass('moved').appendTo(place_holder_select_field);
        }
    });
}
```

```js
//Create on DOM element dynamically that will house options greater than three.
var blank_input = $('<select>', {
    class: 'hidden_input_field hide',
    name: 'hidden_fields'
});

//This variable caches the master select element.
var master_select_menu = jQuery('#cd-dropdown');

//Put the blank select field in the DOM tree to be select via jQuery selectors.
blank_input.appendTo(jQuery('body'));

jQuery('.view_more_button').on('click', function(e) {
 var place_holder_select_field = jQuery('.hidden_input_field');
 if (place_holder_select_field.children('option').length) {
  jQuery('.moved').each(function(index,element) {
   jQuery(element).appendTo(master_select_menu);
  });
  jQuery(e.target).addClass('hide');
  jQuery('.view_less_button').removeClass('hide');
 }
 master_select_menu.val(-1).change();
});

jQuery('.view_less_button').on('click', function(e) {
 view_three();
 jQuery(e.target).addClass('hide');
 jQuery('.view_more_button').removeClass('hide');
 master_select_menu.val(-1).change();
});

view_three();

//This function gets called as soon as the page loads, where it appends any option element greater than 3 to the hidden select field.
function view_three() {
 jQuery('option').each(function(index, element) {
  var place_holder_select_field = jQuery('.hidden_input_field');
  if (index > 3) {
   jQuery(element).addClass('moved').appendTo(place_holder_select_field);
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.hide {
    left: -9999px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -500;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Funds in your portfolio (3)</option>
    <option value="1">fund1 £60,000</option>
    <option value="2">fund 2 £40,000</option>
    <option value="3">fund 3 £24,000</option>
    <option value="4">View all funds &gt;</option>
    <option value="5">Fund 5 £40,000</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="View all" class='view_more_button' />
<input type="button" value="View less" class='view_less_button hide' />
```